# How to convert Unicode dictionary key and value to string values?

Tags: python, json

I want to read json file and convert it to dict. Seems to be easy... But I have a problem with enoding. When I used `json.load(file`) it saves content of a file to a dict as `u'key':u'value'`. Is it possible to save content of `json.load(file)` to a dict as `"key":"value"` or convert dict with unicodes to dict with strings?

Comment: Do you work with (the outdated) Python 2?

Comment: @Matthias, Yes,I work with python 2.7.18

Comment: I think it is saving the correct Unicode data, but when you print it, Python/JSON formats it that way. When you load it again is it correct?

Comment: Keys and values are unicode strings. If you look at the representation of the dictionary Python will show you the strings representation and that has a leading `u`. The representation of a value is not the value itself. But let me ask you: The death of Python 2 was announced over 10 years ago. Why don't you switch to Python 3?